# Make notification Large Icon round in react-native-firebase

Tags: react-native, push-notification, react-native-firebase

I've been making this aplication where I use *react-native-firebase* and everything works fine, but there's a thing that causes me conflict: I have to show a picture(icon) from a URL in this app and when i set it with the *setLargeIcon()* method, it does appear inside the notification but it shows as a square.

[image: screenshot]

Honestly this doesnt look good and mi UI/UX designer is  rejecting this app because of this. I've looked into the docs but I havent found a solution yet.

My code is the following:

```
 const notification = new firebase.notifications.Notification()
      .setTitle(title)
      .setBody(body)
      .setSound(sound)
      .setData(data)

    notification.android.setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL)
    notification.android.setSmallIcon('ic_notification')
    notification.android.setColor(primaryColor)
    notification.android.setAutoCancel(true)
    notification.android.setLargeIcon(data.icon || assets.ilDefaultAvatar)
    if (Platform.OS === 'android' && Platform.Version >= 24 && conversationId) {
      notification.android.setGroup(conversationId)
      notification.android.setGroupAlertBehaviour(
        firebase.notifications.Android.GroupAlert.Children
      )
    }

    await firebase.notifications().displayNotification(notification)
```

How do I make it round?

Answer (score 0):

You must set them in your android project. Open Android studio and follow this steps explained [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio#notification).

Comment: I think I didnt explained myself clear here, the image I want it to be round is the one on the right, I know how to the se default notification's icon.

Comment: So the icon you made is round but its being shown up square? Are you sure you made a circle icon with the icons tool?

Comment: This is the tool I use to make the round icons:
https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/

Comment: I forgot to mention that I render that Icon from a URL @J. Nicastro

Comment: Can you add that to the question? @miguelacio